# FileZilla can't connect to the local FTP Server and showing error logs on its server

Tags: windows-8.1, ftp, iis, filezilla

I am running FTP Server on Windows 8.1 Pro with IIS. It operates good along. But today , it shows error logs that pending error loops like this below.Main error is about `Retrieving directory listing...`. My root directory is `D:\`. I can access it from Chrome on mobile and PC.

```
Status  :   Connecting to 192.168.1.38:21...
Status  :   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status  :   Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status  :   Logged in
Status  :   Retrieving directory listing...
Command :   PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command :   TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command :   PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (171,100,164,212,39,145).
Command :   LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error   :   The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - 
            Connection attempt timed out
Response:   550-Data channel timed out.
Response:   Win32 error: The network connection was aborted by the local 
            system. 
Response:   Error details: Data channel timed out.
Response:   550 End
Error   :   Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status  :   Retrieving directory listing...
Command :   CDUP
Response:   250 CDUP command successful.
Command :   PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command :   PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (171,100,164,212,39,169).
Command :   LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error   :   The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - 
            Connection attempt timed out
        .
        .
        .
  going forever
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/279286/210623